# How to get tweets older than a month using Twitter API 1.1 and PHP

Tags: php, api, twitter

I have created a script in PHP that fetches tweets based on a particular keyword.
I works fine, but it returns only tweets up to 1 week or 9 days.
I need a work around that will help get tweets older than a month.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php 

include "twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php";

$consumer_key = "consumer_key";
$consumer_secret = "consumer_secret ";
$access_token = "access_token ";
$access_token_secret = "access_token_secret ";

$twitter = new TwitterOAuth($consumer_key,$consumer_secret,$access_token,$access_token_secret);

$tweets = $twitter->get('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=investcorp&result_type=recent&count=500&since_id=2016-05-25&lang=en');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Twitter API SEARCH</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php foreach ($tweets->statuses as $key => $tweet) { ?>
    Tweet : <img src="<?=$tweet->user->profile_image_url;?>" /><?=$tweet->text; ?><br>
<?php } ?>


</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

2018 update: Twitter has Premium search APIs that can provide data and counts from the previous 30 days or Tweets from as early as 2006:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/overview/premium#ProductPackages

Comment: This is paid right?. Is there a way by which we can get something that is open source, or any modification in code

Comment: There is no way, afaik.

Comment: Free! But you have to go through an approval process which can be slow.

Comment: @Jonas can you send me a link through which I can apply for the approval process.